# Display Image in QML from response to XmlHttpRequest (REST)

Tags: qt, qml

I need to fetch a jpeg image from a REST API call. I use XMLHttpRequest as the request requires authentication headers (i.e. I can't just create an Image and set the source to the URL with user:passwd@url).

I thought I'd be able to use a Canvas and call drawImage by setting the REST data to a CanvasImageData object. However, it doesn't draw anything, nor does it produce an error. The REST call returns Content-Type: image/jpeg and the Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

Should this approach work, or am I missing something else? Any better suggestions?

```
// map_request.imageBytes is a property that holds the binary response from the REST query
Canvas {
id: location_map
width: 2400
height: 1500
contextType: '2d'

onPaint: {
  if (context && map_request.imageBytes)
  {
    var cid = context.createImageData(width, height);
    cid.data = map_request.imageBytes;
    context.drawImage(cid, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `cid.data` must be image pixel data in RGBA order, not raw image data.  Can you receive the image as base64 encoded string from the server? In this case you can create an image as `img.source='data:image/png;base64,...encoded data here ...'`. Another workaround is to use custom image provider.

Comment: You know, that should be an answer to upvote @folibis :)

Comment: I suspect I'll need to switch to a custom image provider, as I can't get base64 encoded image data. Thanks for clarifying the format of the CanvasImageData.  Please feel free to create an answer to my question, and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: @folibis I tried to take the binary PNG data and use Qt.btoa() to set the image.source as you describe. However, the result is a QML error:
`QML Image: Error decoding: data:image/png;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAH77+9AAACIAgCAAAAEO+/
`

Comment: Yes, that happens because of wrong byte conversion. Anyway this method is not what you should use. Encoding to base64 will increase the array size up to ~30%. The best way I think is to implement own `QQuickImageProvider` with subclass of `QNetworkAccessManager`. For authentification purpose you should use `QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired` signal.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to create a QQuickImageProvider as @folibis instructed. However, since I am using Qt5.5, I can't make a QQuickAsyncImageProvider (which is introduced in Qt5.6). Instead, you have to set the Flags when constructing the QQuickImageProvider to QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading. This flag ensures that calling requestImage doesn't block the main GUI thread.

However, requestImage expects the Image to be returned, causing a challenge to fetch the Image data from the network without blocking that thread. QNetworkAccessManager returns its status with signals, and QQuickImageProvider isn't a QObject, so I made a helper class to monitor the signals for the QNetworkReply.

```
class ReplyMonitor : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ReplyMonitor(QNetworkAccessManager *);

public Q_SLOTS:
  void handleReplyFinished();
  void handleSslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &);
  void handleAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *);

public:
  bool finished;
};
```

and

```
ReplyMonitor::ReplyMonitor(QNetworkAccessManager *mgr)
  : finished(false)
{
  connect(mgr, SIGNAL( finished(QNetworkReply *) ), this, SLOT( handleReplyFinished() ));
  connect(mgr, SIGNAL( sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &) ),
          this, SLOT( handleSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> &) ));
  connect(mgr, SIGNAL( authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *) ),
          this, SLOT( handleAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*) ));
}

void ReplyMonitor::handleReplyFinished()
{
  finished = true;
}
```

Then in `requestImage()` I check `finished` and call

```
  while (!monitor->finished)
  {
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 1000);
  }
```

before I create the Image to return with

```
  if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
  {
    image.loadFromData(reply->readAll());
  }
```

I omitted the details of creating a QNetworkRequest, as that is well-documented.