# Qml request a image file, receiving blob string, how to display?

Tags: c++, image, matrix, qml, blob

Sorry, Im still a beginner in qml but I have not found an easy solution for this here.
Im creating a pure qml based Matrix Messenger. When I request images from the homeserver, I receive a strange string, which I don't know how to display this:

```
Image {
    id: avatar
    name: "contact"
    anchors.fill: parent
    Component.onCompleted: {
          var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
          http.open( "GET", requestUrl, true);
          http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
          http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
          http.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if ( responseType = "image/png" ) {

                   // So this does not work :-(
                   avatar.source = http.responseText

              }
         }
         http.send( JSON.stringify( /* The mxc uri ... */ ) );
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea, how I can display this file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Image in QML from response to XmlHttpRequest (REST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852856/display-image-in-qml-from-response-to-xmlhttprequest-rest)

Comment: Maybe the question is not a real duplicate, but the answer should help you getting further. The problem in a nutshell: `Image {}` expects some sort of URL to an image, not the image data itself.

Comment: Why don't you just replace all this code with `source: imageurl` ? It does exactly what your code does.